# Does Office 365 support standalone MAPI calls

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

Is it possible to create an RDOSession with Office 365 without having Outlook installed (I have installed Microsoft Messaging API and Collaboration Data Objects on the computer in question)

I am trying to use

```
RDOSession := RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession;
RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox('<SMTPAddress>', '<Username>', '<password>');
```

but I get the ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but Exchange 2016 and 2019 explicitly refuse connections coming from the standalone version of MAPI (whcih does not support MAPI-over-HTTP).

But in your particular case, it sounds like the error occurs even before configuring the MSEMS provider, when Redemption attempts to retrieve the autodiscover XML to configure the profile and one of the possible urls constructed from the SMTP address cannot be resolved. In most cases that would be fine, since Redemption can attempt to retrieve the autodiscover XML from multiple source.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but when I said Office 365, I meant the hosted, online version of Exchange.  Does that mean that I cannot do it as the the connection requests will be refused (as for Exchange 2016 / 2019)?

Comment: Yes, since Office 365 uses Exchange 2019

Comment: @Andrew - if the reply answers your question, please mark it as such.